# Keeping both Minsc and Jaheira in party - Where to go next?

Tags: baldurs-gate

I just adopted Minsc. Nice stats there, buddy! Jaheira is already pissing and moaning because we're taking too long to get to the mines. Minsc wants us to go rescue Dynaheir. I don't want Dynaheir, I'm a mage and I understand she's not a very good one anyway. I've tried (and already failed) to not look at walkthroughs too much, but I see that my best option regarding Dynaheir might be to just let her die.

At any rate, I think I want to keep both Minsc and Jaheira (unless you have better advice?). I know from my recent playing of *Torment* that I'll always play as a do-gooder (my willingness to kill Dynaheir, who I haven't even *met* yet, aside). So where to next? The mines? (I've talked to the mayor of Nashkell so I assume that quest is open (?), or to the Gnoll Stronghold?

Comment: Ah. Good old BG days..  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep Minsc in your party, you have to rescue Dynaheir. After a period of time, he will leave your party if you have not rescued her. In addition, if she leaves the party afterwards, he will also leave. He will also go into a berserker rage if she dies, turning hostile.

Jaheira is similarly tied to Khalid. She will leave the party if he is kicked out, and vice versa.

However, there is a trick to separating pairs, although it is a bit of an exploit. You can enter a building that you never plan on entering again, move the character you want to abandon to the opposite side of the map, kick them out, and then exit the building quickly before anyone can initiate dialog. You should be able to avoid losing their partner if you act quickly enough. Otherwise, you can allow one to die and then remove them from the party safely (with the exception of Minsc due to his rage).

As for where to go next - I think the trigger to keep Jaheira and Khalid in the party is to simply talk to the mayor, which you have already done. Minsc's quest timer is relatively short if I remember correctly, so I would reccomend grabbing Dynaheir as soon as possible, although it is definitely feasible to complete the mines before attempting her rescue, dependent on your resting habits.

Comment: Hmmm, will Minsc eventually calm down if Dynaheir dies? I've got ridiculously high charisma, if that helps. I'm thinking of loading up on healing potions (for myself), stripping him of weapons, and just playing psychiatric nurse for a while. If I do need to keep Dynaheir for a while, Imoen will always wait for me, right?

Comment: Yes to both questions :)

Comment: Heehee...even better, don't lead her to death, get her to turn herself into stone! I got one short NOOO from Minsc, then he was saying, "Go for the eyes, Boo, go for the eyes!" (towards bad guys, not me) :) Gotta love grunts, not the brightest bulbs in the chandelier.